# Why doesn't Pinescript recognise DEMA?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have pinescript indicator code. there is a problem about DEMA but I couldn't solve it. Could you help me?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Trading Strategy", overlay=true)

// MACD Dema line between -1 and +1 and turned up
macdDemaLine = ta.dema(ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9), 14)
macdDemaCondition = macdDemaLine > -1 and macdDemaLine < 1 and ta.change(macdDemaLine) > 0

// RSI between 20 and 60 and crossed up SMMA (RMA) 14
rsiCondition = ta.rsi(close, 14) > 20 and ta.rsi(close, 14) < 60 and ta.cross(close, ta.sma(ta.rsi(close, 14), 14))

// Close price above EMA 14
emaCondition = close > ta.ema(close, 14)

// Entry condition
entryCondition = macdDemaCondition and rsiCondition and emaCondition

// Plot Buy Signals
plotshape(entryCondition, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, size=size.small)
```

I need to find solution

Answer (score 0):

your problem lies within the first line of code.

```
ta.dema(ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9), 14)
```

`ta.macd()` returns a `tuple` with two values in it (`MACD` and `Signal`).
You trying to put both values in a field which can accept one value only.

Solution ...

```
[macdLine, siganlLine] = ta.macd(close, 12, 26, 9)
macdDemaLine = ta.dema(macdLine, 14)
```

Addition ...

to get `ta.dema()` to work you will also need to import a library. Add the following line at the top to your code ...

```
import TradingView/ta/5
```